# Setup server for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

working under linux server Centos remotly in local network, my rails server working there too. How can I enable remote web access? And if so how can I enable only couple of ip addresses for web access?

Comment: question about rails configuration, not about network administration! can I enable not only localhost access, and filtering ip adresses by rails mechanism. Sorry for so incorrect question, and not enough clearly formulated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check on which addresses the server applications binds. If it has no external IP-Address then it wont be possible to access it directly from the internet. Then it is possible to use port forwarding to forward your application over your router. If you havent any access to the router you should ask the administrator of your network to forward it for you.

Another possibility is to plug a VLAN to a secound interface but you should think about security when you have a server that is connected to your NATed network and the internet directly!

Answer (score 0):

if its only rails production server setup then you can try with this:

http://www.leonardteo.com/2012/11/install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-server/

it uses https://github.com/ballistiq/ruby-passenger-nginx-installer and they are maintaining the installer. I found its very helpful. it works like no-pain